# Função nativa xmlhttprequest não sobescreve passando Token de usuario no header

Tags: javascript, localstorage, xmlhttprequest

Estou com dificuldade para que a minha função sobescreva a função nativa xmlhttprequest para que sempre passe um header contendo o token de usúario que está contido no meu LocalStorage 
Atualmente meu código está assim:

```
// const oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send
// const oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open

class overrideXmlHTTPRequest {
static override () {
const token = localStorage.getItem('userToken')
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
const xhrProto = XMLHttpRequest.prototype
const origOpen = xhrProto.open

xhrProto.open = function (method, url) {
  this._url = url
  return origOpen.apply(this, arguments)
}
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
}
xhrProto.send = function () {
  xhrProto.setRequestHeader('UserToken', token)
}
}
}

export default overrideXmlHTTPRequest
```

Dessa forma quando chamo overrideXmlHTTPRequest.override() num meu outro arquivo .vue O header continua padrão e nada foi sobescrito

Answer (score 0):

Usando Jquery, acredito que a seguinte solução resolva seu problema:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
   'TOKEN': 123
  }
});
```

Comment: Não há alguma maneira de fazer isso com javascript puro sem utilizar o Jquery?

Comment: Você pode usar o metodo setRequestHeader.

XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("UserToken", 123);

Tem que fazer essa chamada após o metodo XMLHttpRequest.open e antes da chamada XMLHttpRequest.send

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o metodo setRequestHeader.

XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("UserToken", 123);

Tem que fazer essa chamada após o metodo XMLHttpRequest.open e antes da chamada XMLHttpRequest.send